# Assign dynamic index in array of object in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

If I have array of object in such a way.

```
data[0].name= 'Prashant Shukla';
$scope.getColumn[i].Field = 'name';
```

Using above I want to assign `Prashant` in `$scope.getColumn[i].value` in dynamic way. I have try like this

```
$scope.getColumn[i].value = data[0].+$scope.getColumn[i].Field;
```

but this give me `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token +`

I can get `Prashant Shukla` by `data[0].name` but How can I get exactly same by using `$scope.getColumn[i].Field` in place of `name` index ?

how can I resolve this error and assign value dynamically?

thanks ahead.

Comment: Can you provide us some example in plunker or jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use as like as given below:

```
data[0].name= 'Prashant Shukla';
$scope.getColumn[i].Field = 'name';

console.log( data[0][ $scope.getColumn[i].Field ] );  // 'Prashant Shukla'
```

Comment: thanks Sabbir. It works. Well I think you are Indian and this is mid night for indian time. I am very happy to see you are working in this time :-)

Comment: You are welcome. It's awesome that I can help you. I'm not Indian, I'm Bangladeshi.

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.getColumn[i].value = data[0].+$scope.getColumn[i].Field;
```

Why you have `.` after the `data[0]`?

It should be `data[0].name +$scope.getColumn[i].Field;`

Comment: Because I have fetch data in array of object format.

Comment: I think you are not getting what I want to ask. please read again my question.

Comment: But this syntax is not make sense... you can't write `data[0].+`

Comment: Definitely this syntax not make sense but  How can I write?

Comment: I can get  "Prashant Shukla" by "data[0].name" but How can I get exactly same by using "$scope.getColumn[i].Field" in place of "name" index